# Convert Joda DateTime to Wall Time on Android Device

Tags: android, datetime, timezone, jodatime, utc

I have a Joda DateTime that I need to display on an Android device in Wall Time.
My data is all stored in UTC so I need to make sure dates and times are displayed in the user's local time zone.

For example, in Europe/London, `2016-03-29T15:00:00.000Z` would be displayed on the device as 16:00.

Comment: This seems to do the trick:

`new DateTime(utcDateTime, DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()));`

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `DateTime`, you could first convert it to the local time zone then get the local time:

```
LocalTime userTime = dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).toLocalTime();
```